# Finding the value of the determinant $|M^2+MN^2|$ and determining whether $U$ is a zero matrix or not

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Let $M$ and $N$ be two $3\times 3$ matrices such that $MN=NM$. Further
>   if $M\neq N^2$ and $M^2=N^4$ then what is/are the possible value(s) of
>   the determinant $|M^2+MN^2|$? Also if there is a $3\times 3$ matrix
>   $U$ such that $(M^2+MN^2)U=O$ can we say whether $U$ is a zero matrix or
>   a non-zero matrix ?

---

**My Attempt:**

$|M|=\pm|N|^2$ (from $M^2=N^4$)

---

$(M-N)(N-M)=M^2-N^2$ (as $MN=NM$)

---

$M^2=N^4$

$\implies MMN=N^5$

$\implies NMMN=N^6$

$\implies MNMN=N^6$

$\implies (MN)^2=N^6$

---

Similarly, $M^6=(MN)^4$

---

These are what I could deduce from the given information. How should I proceed from here to solve the question?

Comment: The elements are real?

Comment: @EugenCovaci Yes.

Comment: I don't understand the condition "such that $(M^2+MN^2)U$"

Comment: @EugenCovaci Sorry, corrected! $O$ stands for zero matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first note that $M$ and $N^2$ commute because $M$ and $N$ do. Because of this, we may write $$0 = M^2 - N^4 = (M-N^2)(M+N^2).$$
This tells us that $|M+N^2| = 0$, since if it wasn't, you could multiply both sides by the inverse $(M+N^2)^{-1}$ to find $0 = M - N^2$ and hence $M = N^2$, which isn't allowed.

But $M^2 + MN^2 = M(M+N^2)$, hence $$|M(M+N^2)| = |M||M+N^2| = |M| \cdot 0 = 0.$$

As for the second part, you can't say anything about $U$. For example, take $M = -I$ and $N = I$. These satisfy the conditions, but $M^2 + MN^2 = 0$, so obviously $(M^2 + MN^2)U = 0$ for any matrix $U$.

Comment: How can we say $M^2+MN^2=0$ ? It is possible that even if matrix is non zero it's determinant can be zero. So $(M^2+MN^2)U=0$ is not necessarily True. Isn't it?

Comment: @mathophile I didn't claim $M^2+MN^2 = 0$ anywhere, only that its determinant $|M^2+MN^2| = 0$.

Comment: Then How your this statement so obviously $(M^2 + MN^2)U = 0$ for any matrix $U$. can be true?

Comment: Ah, yes, I did claim $M^2+MN^2 = 0$ there, I missed that in my previous reply. However, I'm talking about the example $M = -I$ and $N = I$ there, not the general case.

Comment: So the general statement **there is a $3 \times 3$ non-zero matrix $$ such that $(^2 + M^2)$ is the zero matrix.** This question was asked in Jee advanced exam 2014 Paper 1. There they gave this statement as true. I think this statement should be wrong.

Comment: Source https://www.jeeadv.ac.in/archive.html

Comment: That statement ( (B) in the exam paper you mention) is true, but it's not covered by this question and my answer. To prove it, you could use the Jordan form to show that $M^2+MN^2$ is similar to a matrix whose first column consists of only zeroes. If you want a more detailed answer, I suggest you start a new question.