# Let $M$ and $N$ be two $3\times 3$ matrices such that $MN=NM$, Further if $M\neq N^2$ and $M^2=N^4$ then

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, jordan-normal-form

> > Let $M$ and $N$ be two  $3\times 3$ matrices such that $MN=NM$, Further if $M\neq N^2$ and $M^2=N^4$ then

> > (A) Determinant of $(M^2+MN^2)$ is $0$

> > (B) There is a non-zero $3\times 3$ matrix $U$ such that $(M^2+MN^2)U$ is the zero matrix

> > (C) Determinant of $(M^2+MN^2) \geq1$

> > (D) For a $3\times 3$ Matrix $U$, if $(M^2+MN^2)U$ equals the zero matrix then $U$ is the zero matrix.

**My Thinking:**

$(M-N^2)(M+N^2)=M^2-N^4+MN^2-N^2M$

$\implies$ $(M-N^2)(M+N^2)=MNN-NNM=NMN-NMN=0$ (Here zero denotes Null matrix).

**Case $(1)$** $M+N^2 \neq0$ and $M-N^2= 0$ (Here zero is Null matrix)

But it is given that $M\neq N^2$

So Case $1$ Can't be true.

**Case$(2)$** $M-N^2\neq 0$ and $M+N^2\neq 0$

But we know that $|M-N^2||M+N^2|=0$

$\implies$ $|M+N^2||M-N^2|= 0$

So

Subcase $(1)$ of case $(2)$ $|M+N^2|=0$ and $|M-N^2|\neq 0$

Subcase $(2)$ of case $(2)$ $|M+N^2|\neq 0$ and $|M-N^2|=0$

But when $|M+N^2|\neq0$ then we can take inverse of this.

$\implies$

$0=(M+N^2)(M-N^2)$

$\implies$

$0=(M+N^2)^{-1}(M+N^2)(M-N^2)$

$\implies$

$0= M-N^2$ i.e. subcase $(2)$ is false.

$\implies$ Result of case $(2)$ is $|M+N^2|=0$

**Case $(3)$**

$M+N^2=0$ and $M-N^2\neq 0$

Result of case $(3)$ is $|M+N^2|=0$

If above is  true then Matrix $(M+N^2)=0$

**From All three cases $|M+N^2|=0$**.

So Option $(A)$ is True.

**My Doubt is option (B)**

I think this statement should be false because $(M^2+MN^2)U$ need not be zero always.

**This question was asked in Indian Exam JEE Advanced Paper $1$ of Year $2014$ https://www.jeeadv.ac.in/archive.html**

Linked Question [Finding the value of the determinant $|M^2+MN^2|$ and determining whether $U$ is a zero matrix or not](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2269960/finding-the-value-of-the-determinant-m2mn2-and-determining-whether-u-is/2270046?noredirect=1#comment9132773_2270046)

Comment: Part (B) says "*there is a matrix* $\mathit{U}$" : so all you need is *one* matrix for which it is zero. Of course, $U$ itself being the zero matrix works. You also haven't said anything about part $(D)$ (note that option $(C)$ is obviously false if $(A)$ is true.)

Comment: $(A)$ and $(C)$ look contradict to each other?!

Comment: @LeonardNeon The question is which of the statements are true. The solution manual says (A) and (B) are true, but OP has doubts about (B) really being true.

Comment: Also, I think in (B) you want to specify that $U$ is non-zero, which is done in the exam paper you link to.

Comment: @sTertooy Yes, I've Edited the question.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer There was typing error. In question $U$ is a non-zero Matrix.

Comment: @mathophile Ouch, that's my fault as well. I should have seen the source, I apologize. Having said that, the answer below stands in any case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by @SarveshRavichandranIyer, you only need to prove the existence of *one* matrix $U$ such that $(M^2+MN^2)U = 0$, not that it holds for any $U$.

You've already proven that (A) is true, i.e. the determinant $|M^2+MN^2| = 0$. For the sake of simplicity, let's set $A := M^2+MN^2$. We know that $|A| = 0$ and have to prove that there exists *some* matrix $U$ such that $AU = 0$.

Because $|A| = 0$, the columns of $A$ are linearly dependent. Let's say that $c_1 = x\, c_2 + y\, c_3$, where $c_i$ is the $i$-th column of $A$. Now let
$$U := \begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\-x&-x&-x\\-y&-y&-y\\\end{pmatrix}.$$
It's easy to verify that $AU = 0$, but $U$ is a non-zero matrix.